# RSS/Python - Parsing Single Image URL

Tags: python, parsing, rss, feedparser

I'm in the works of learning to parse xml and rss feeds correctly and have run in to a little problem. I'm using feedbarser in python to parse a specific entry from an RSS feed, but can't figure out how to parse just a single img src from the content section.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import dirFeedparser.feedparser as feedparser

feedurl = feedparser.parse('http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/index.php?cat=22&feed=rss2')
statusupdate = feedurl.entries[0].content

print statusupdate
```

Now, when I print the content I get this:

```
[{'base': u'http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/index.php?cat=22&feed=rss2', 'type': u'text/html', 'value': u'<p><a href="http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/20120129-154945.jpg"><img alt="20120129-154945.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" src="http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/20120129-154945.jpg" /></a></p>', 'language': None}]
```

What method would be best to get the IMG SRC from that? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The value you have shown us it it `content` or `statusupdate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lattyware, you have some problem with setting soap.

@user1130601, you can check the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import feedparser

feedurl = feedparser.parse('http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/index.php?cat=22&feed=rss2')
statusupdate = feedurl.entries[0].content


soup = BeautifulSoup(statusupdate[0]['value'])
print(soup.find("img")["src"])
```

Output:

```
http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/20120129-171134.jpg
```

Comment: After having to make a couple modifications to feedparser.py and to this, I managed to get my results perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You then want to use a separate HTML parser to parse the HTML and get the `img`'s `src` attribute. You might want to look into [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

e.g:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import feedparser

feedurl = feedparser.parse('http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/index.php?cat=22&feed=rss2')
statusupdate = feedurl.entries[0].content[0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(statusupdate["value"])
print(soup.find("img")["src"])
```

Note that this simply uses the first `img` tag it finds. If you need to be more selective, look at [`findall`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a good HTML parser, try BeautifulSoup.

It's easy to parse with it:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(statusupdate['value'])
url = soup.find('img').src
```

Comment: The element is a dictionary, so you need to access the attribute with ["src"] not .src - as in my answer.

Comment: BeautifulSoup works with either approach. The element *acts* like a dictionary, but is a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` object.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work for me. I accessed it as a dictionary-like object, and it worked, as an attribute, I got None. I just tried again to the same end

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [lxml](http://lxml.de/) . With lxml you can use [xpath expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Here x is your statusupdate.

```
from lxml import etree
st = x[0]["value"]
doc = etree.fromstring(st)
value = doc.xpath("//img/@src") #xpath expr = //img/@src
"".join(value)
```

Output = `'http://dustinheroin.chompblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/20120129-154945.jpg'`